# I am trying to solve a system of equation with two variable in tkinter python

Tags: python

Good morning,

I am trying to solve a system of equation with 2 variables in Python, but using Tkinter to display the answers on the screen. I did most of it, but I can not display the answes.

That is the error I am seeing:

```
enter coException in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\edwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\edwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\ed.py", line 122, in Calculate
    z = np.linalg.solve ( a, b)
  File "C:\Users\edwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 375, in solve
    r = gufunc(a, b, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
  File "C:\Users\edwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 90, in _raise_linalgerror_singular
    raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrixde here
```

Comment: You should add some of your actual code to the question so we can see exactly what you're attempting to do. Just showing a traceback isn't enough for us to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

A singular matrix is [not invertible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix). A singular matrix does not satisfy the property: The equation Ax = b has exactly one solution for each b in Kn. This means that the system you are attempting to solve is either incorrectly converted into matrix form, or does not have a unique solution.

Comment: I am trying to solve an Equation at two variable. That is the code right here:

Comment: #Create a Calculate function
def Calculate ():
    Y1 =DoubleVar ()
    Z1 =DoubleVar ()
    X2 =DoubleVar ()
    Y2 =DoubleVar ()
    Z2 =DoubleVar () 
    x1 = DoubleVar()
    y1 = DoubleVar()
    x2 =DoubleVar ()
    y2 = DoubleVar()
    C1 = DoubleVar()
    C2 = DoubleVar()
    X1=DoubleVar ()
    Item0 = float(X1.get())
    Item1 = float(Y1.get())
    Item2 = float(X2.get())
    Item3= float(Y2.get())
    Item4 = float(Z1.get())
    Item5 = float(Z2.get())
    A = DoubleVar()
    B = DoubleVar()
    C = DoubleVar()
    Values = DoubleVar()

Comment: A = np.array ([[Item0,Item1], [ Item2,Item3]])# Display the equation
    B =np.array([Item4,Item5])#Display the two =
    C = np.linalg.solve ( A, B)
    #Values = float(C.get())
    C1 = C[0]
    C2 = C[1]
    x1.set(C[0])
    y1.set(C[1])
    return

Comment: here it is the button function:  Button1 = Button (f11, text = " Calculate ",command = Calculate, font=("arial",30,"bold"),bd = 5)
Button1.pack()